# Wordpress Admin Login contains double URL in redirect_to

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-redirect

I moved my wordpress homepage today. After updating the site url in the prefences and also updating every other link with the search and replace plugin, I still have an issue.

When i navigate to the wordpress admin login via wordpress-url.com/wp-admin it redirects me to

```
https://wordpress-url.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwordpress-url.com%2Fwordpress-url.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

as you can see, the URL is in the redirect_to twice. 
As a result, whenever i try to login, it just refreshs the page and nothing else happens.

After another bit of research, it might be because of the .htaccess files

I have one file in the root directory for my domain that redirects to my wordpress directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wordpress-url.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wordpress-url.come$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress-url.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wordpress-url.com/$1 [L]
```

And another one in my wordpress directory, which has been created by wordpress itself.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can anyone help me finding the issue?

Comment: Well, we can’t find what’s wrong with your code if you don’t show us your code.

Comment: I did not change anything about the default wordpress code. I'm also using the default wordpress twentyseventeen theme.

Comment: what are your settings for home url and site url?

Comment: home url and site url are both `https://wordpress-url.com`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wordpress-url.come$
```

Should be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wordpress-url.com$
```